# use char* to compare with a value on string

Tags: c, c89

Hi I use the function strtok to split an array as follows:

```
char str[] ="one11;one2";
char* pch;
pch = strtok (str,";");
while (pch != NULL)
    pch = strtok(NULL, ";");
```

Now I need to compare my pointer pch with a specific value, let's say:

```
if (pch == "one11")
  // do this
```

Although I am getting the first part of the string, in this case 'one11' the comparison fails. Is there a way to compare these two things?

Thanks,

Comment: See function `strcmp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compare strings use standard function `strcmp` declared in header `<string.h>`. For example

```
#include <string.h>

//..
char str[] ="one11;one2";
char* pch;
pch = strtok (str,";");
while ( pch != NULL && strcmp( pch, "one11" ) != 0 )
    pch = strtok(NULL, ";");
```

If the first string is less than the second string the function returns a negative value. If strings are equal then the function returns 0. And if the first string is greater than the second string the function returns a positive value.

Comment: oh i thought that strcmp needed to secure space for each variable, I did not know that even pointers work. Thanks.